# Electron: Open default email client

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using election framework to built .exe and .dmg files. In the app I have a button, clicking on which it must open default email application installed on the system to send an email.
Following is the code to open email client

```
shell.openExternal("mailto:xyz@abc.com?subject=MySubject&body=");
```

But, it only works on few systems.

Note: It is already checked that other systems also have default email client.
Is there any better way to do it. So, it will work on all system?
Thanks in advance for providing help and your precious time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the code `shell.openExternal("mailto:xyz@abc.com?subject=MySubject&body=");` only launches the MUA which is configured as the default in the system settings. Oftentimes in older version of windows there is no default mail client set and so it won’t work regardless.